# How to override WooCommerce template files

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to override WooCommerce template files as they told us

copy: `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/archive-product.php` to `wp-content/themes/your_theme_name/woocommerce/archive-product.php`

But I can't find the WooCommerce folder inside my theme folder. I'm using Astra theme.

Comment: [Template structure & Overriding](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) from the WooCommerce documentation - in particular see the note about add_theme_support. You should probably customising a child theme though, not Astra itself.

Answer (score 0):

You should create it. The way woocommerce overriding templates work is that it tries to look for the template in your theme, and when not found falls back to it's own.

So if you create the exact file structure the woocommerce expects, you'll be able to override their templates.

I would also consider to try and not do it, and use filters instead if possible, since filters are a much more flexible and future proof solution. When woocommerce will update, the template can change, but you'll be still with your old one. In case of filters on the other hand, the filter will still work, and you'll have the advantage of the new template.

Comment: There's only so much you can do with filters with the woocommerce templates, though. You can add things in specific places but you can't make significant changes to what's already there.

Comment: Agree. I also edited my comment to say "if possible". I just added this additional bit of information, cause in most cases using filters was enough for me. But yes - sometimes it's not enough, and then the overriding strategy is stated in the first sentence.